# is this sentence correct and readable?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this grammatical and readable?

A politician should consult with his party before declaring his intentions for the next election.

Comment: Some would argue that you should say "his or her" party to be gender neutral. Others would recommend substituting a singular "their" for the same reason. Then others will claim that both of these are completely wrong and unacceptable. Shortly thereafter, the discussion will break down into verbal poo-flinging.  My point is that no matter what you use in this case, someone will declare you 100% wrong for using it.

Comment: Why do you think it might or might not be grammatical? This question is off-topic unless you identify a specific concern.

Comment: I say avoid controversy and change the singular subject to plural and then insert the plural pronoun "they" to replace the antecedent.  I must say, however, I've been trying lately to use "he or she" in sentences in which I replace them later with the word "they." I haven't received any flak for it yet. The first few times I did this, however, I felt a slight twinge of conscience, though I didn't lose any sleep over it! Don

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is grammatically and factually correct.